# How to access anonymous union/struct member from another header data?

Tags: c, gcc

I want to access a member of struct from some header data.
Here is an example from my code:

```
char wk1[2];
union 
{
    unsigned short WORD;
    struct 
    {
        unsigned short SSBY:1;
        unsigned short OPE:1;
    } BIT;
} SBYCR;
char           wk3[5];
union {
    unsigned char BYTE;
    struct {
        unsigned char :7;
        unsigned char BCLKDIV:1;
    } BIT;
} BCKCR;
```

I want to set the bit`SSBY to 0` in my main. and tried to access it directly in my main:

```
void main()
{
  SBYCR.BIT.SSBY=0;
}
```

but it gives me an error E0520020:Identifier "SBYCR" is undefined.
I tried to define it again like:

```
union SBYCR BIT; //but it has an error E0520070:Incomplete type is not allowed
SBYCR.BIT.SSBY=0; // and this, it doesn't recognise the BIT i want, while i have so many variable called BIT.
```

Comment: Please show us the code you tried that failed.

Comment: What is `struct pointer BIT;` meant to be? There is no `struct pointer` in the snippet

Comment: @Andhika Tidar Prasetyo How is the declaration char           wk1[2]; related to the union definition?

Comment: The union is anonymous, which make it very hard to use that declaration.

Comment: So you want `SBYCR.BIT.SSBY=0`? `E0520070:Incomplete type is not allowed` I do not believe this is a gcc error. Why is `gcc` tagged?

Comment: Note that `SBYCR` is the only variable that can be created of that type.  You cannot create any other variable of that type because the type has no name — there is neither a tag on the union (no `union tag_name { … }`) nor a name given via a typedef: such as `typedef union { … } name_for_union;`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that's is also i don't understand because is the header data, that i got from the microcontroller.

Comment: @KamilCuk i'm sorry if its not because of what iread befor the anonymous union/struct is not a standard of c and its a extended from gcc that's why i thought i shoul tag gcc

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
   SBYCR.BIT.SSBY=0;
```

Comment: yes i want to do this actually but it seems like i cannot easily write it like that